# Why am I getting a 431 status error when passing in a JWT token in Authorization section of the header?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authorization, auth0

So I am creating a full stack React app with Express and Node. I have implemented auth0 for authentication and authorization but I am getting the following error, does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it? Thanks!

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)"
```

The following is the class component where I am calling my api/tasks route and passing in the jwt access token from Auth0.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import {withAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import config from "../auth_config.json";
const {apiOrigin = "http://localhost:3001"} = config

componentDidMount() {
        const getProtectedTasks = async () => {
            const {getAccessTokenSilently} = this.props.auth0;
            const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            try {
                const token = accessToken;
                const self = this;
                const response = await axios.get(`${apiOrigin}/api/tasks`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                })
                self.setState({
                    allTasks: response.data
                })

            } catch {

            }
        }
        getProtectedTasks()

    }
```

The following is my code that handles the get api/tasks endpoint

```
const db = require("../models");
const jwt = require("express-jwt");
const jwksRsa = require("jwks-rsa");

module.exports = function (router) {
    const authorizeAccessToken = jwt({
        secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
            cache:true,
            rateLimit:true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute:5,
            jwksUri: `https://task-motivator.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json`
        }),
        audience: "https://quickstarts/api",
        issuer: "https://task-motivator.us.auth0.com",
        algorithms: ["RS256"]
    });

    router.get("/api/tasks", authorizeAccessToken, (req, res) => {
        db.Task.findAll({}).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: is there a way to get visibility into the actual api call that is made? which part is too big and causes this 431... is it the URL? headers? body? cookie?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due the length of the JWT token. If you don't provide more data, it's difficult to know the reason (as people tell in comments), but try making your data-to-jwt-sign a bit shorter!